# How to convert LaTeX equation into editable equation using Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, latex, google-docs

tldr: How can I convert a LaTeX equation in Google Docs so that it is editable as a Google Doc equation?

Background: I want to import html into Google Docs. This HTML includes (in my native database) LaTeX equations. When I import to Google Docs, the LaTeX is converted into non-editable images. I want to convert the LaTeX into editable Google equations. I'm thinking I can use Google Apps Scripts to accomplish this. My plan is to insert the equations as a text-string "tag" such as `[latex: x + 5 = -3]` - then I'll run a Google Apps Scripts function that converts that tag to a Google Docs equation.

I'm not sure if there's a well-known way to convert LaTeX into Google Apps Scripts equations? Should I just load a javascript library to accomplish this? Would I convert LaTeX to MathML and load that into the Google Apps Scripts equation object?

Answer (score 2):

This genuinely isn't possible - and I tried for ages! The official Docs say that [equations are not supported as insertable types](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/docs), IE they can only be edited in place.

Comment: Just to add to this answer, we have figured out that if you put an equation into a Word Doc, and then import the Word Doc, the equation is editable in Google Docs! Which is nuts, but the only method we've found so far.

Answer (score 0):

Found a free add on called [Auto-Latex Equations add-on for Google Docs](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/autolatex_equations/850293439076?utm_source=tex_stackoverflow_183358). It replaces all the text between $$ signs with high-quality images of the equation.

Basically your tag becomes the delimiters, like $$55 + \sqrt{5}$$ and renders all or one of the equations. If you mess up, you can always undo one or all the equations.

Comment: I don't think this permits importing into GDocs? There are a few plugins that replace GDoc equations, but I don't think any allow you to natively edit GDoc equations. So if someone doesn't have the plugin, the markup doesn't work. This plugin doesn't fix that does it?

Comment: You can just keep them all in native form like within $$ until one person with the add on hits render all --- so only a single collaborator needs it, and everyone can edit and see the results.